# Splitting string columns FAST in R

Tags: regex, r, string, performance

I have a data frame with 107 columns and 745000 rows (much bigger than in my example).

The case is, that I have character type columns which I want to separate, because they seem to contain some type-ish ending at the end of each sequence.

I want to saparate these type-ending parts to new columns.

I have made my own solution, but it seem to be far too slow for iterating through all the 745000 rows 53 times.

So I embed my solution in the following code, with some arbitrary data:

```
set.seed(1)
code_1 <- paste0(round(runif(5000, 100000, 999999)), "_", round(runif(1000, 1, 15)))
code_2 <- sample(c(paste0(round(runif(10, 100000, 999999)), "_", round(runif(10, 1, 15))), NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
code_3 <- sample(c(paste0(round(runif(3, 100000, 999999)), "_", round(runif(3, 1, 15))), NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
code_4 <- sample(c(paste0(round(runif(1, 100000, 999999)), "_", round(runif(1, 1, 15))), NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)

code_type_1 <- rep(NA, 5000)
code_type_2 <- rep(NA, 5000)
code_type_3 <- rep(NA, 5000)
code_type_4 <- rep(NA, 5000)

df <- data.frame(cbind(code_1, 
                       code_2, 
                       code_3, 
                       code_4, 
                       code_type_1, 
                       code_type_2, 
                       code_type_3, 
                       code_type_4), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_new <- data.frame(code_1 = character(),
                     code_2 = character(),
                     code_3 = character(),
                     code_4 = character(),
                     code_type_1 = character(),
                     code_type_2 = character(),
                     code_type_3 = character(),
                     code_type_4 = character(),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:4) {
  i_t <- i + 4
  temp <- strsplit(df[, c(i)], "[_]")
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df_new[c(j), c(i)] <- unlist(temp[j])[1]
    df_new[c(j), c(i_t)] <- ifelse(is.na(unlist(temp[j])[1]), NA, unlist(temp[j])[2])
  }
  print(i)
}

for (i in 1:8) {
 df_new[, c(i)] <- factor(df_new[, c(i)])
}
```

Do anyone have some ideas how to speed things up here?

Comment: what's so slow about this?

Comment: I have provided 5k rows for example, and it still needs some time to process those. This problem tends to grow exponentially if you add more rows to the data. And I have 745000 of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First we pre-allocate the results data.frame to the desired final length. This is very important; see [The R Inferno, Circle 2](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Then we vectorize the inner loop. We also use `fixed = TRUE` and avoid the regex in `strsplit`.

```
system.time({
  df_new1 <- data.frame(code_1 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_2 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_3 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_4 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_type_1 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_type_2 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_type_3 = character(nrow(df)),
                       code_type_4 = character(nrow(df)),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  for (i in 1:4) {
    i_t <- i + 4
    temp <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df[, c(i)], "_", fixed = TRUE))

    df_new1[, i] <- temp[,1]
    df_new1[, i_t] <- ifelse(is.na(temp[,1]), NA, temp[,2])
  }

  df_new1[] <- lapply(df_new1, factor)
})
#   user      system     elapsed 
#  0.029       0.000       0.029 

all.equal(df_new, df_new1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Of course, there are ways to make this even faster, but this is close to your original approach and should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using `gsub` inside a custom function in combination with `purrr::dmap()` - which is equivalent to `lapply`, but outputs a `data.frame` instead of a `list`.

```
library(purrr)  
# Define function which gets rid of everything after and including "_"
replace01 <- function(df, ptrn = "_.*") 
    dmap(df[,1:4], gsub, pattern = ptrn, replacement = "")

# Because "pattern" is argument we can change it to get 2nd part, then cbind()
test <- cbind(replace01(df), 
              replace01(df, ptrn = ".*_"))
```

Note that the output here `character` columns, you can always convert them to factor if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  x <- stri_split_fixed(df[i, 1:4], "_", 2, simplify=TRUE)
  y <- c(x[,1], x[,2])
  y[y==""] <- NA
  y
})), colnames(df)) -> df_new
```

or

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  x <- stri_split_fixed(df[i, 1:4], "_", 2, simplify=TRUE)
  c(x[,1], x[,2])
})), colnames(df)) -> df_new
df_new[df_new==""] <- NA
df_new
```

which is marginally faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 na_after 669.8357 718.1301 724.8803 723.5521 732.9998 790.1405    10  a 
 na_inner 719.3362 738.1569 766.4267 762.1594 791.6198 825.0269    10   b
```